# Use an org-mode code block to execute other code blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I want to use a code block to execute other code blocks with a given language. For example, in my document I want to validate every HTML block using the W3 validator. Currently I do it as follows.

First a code block to validate.

```
#+name: mininal-html-5
#+begin_src html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<title>Minimal HTML 5</title>

<p>Is it valid at all?</p>
#+end_src
```

Next a shell script that validates, getting it's input as a variable. Here together with the result

```
#+name: validate
#+begin_src shell :results output code :wrap src json :var content=mininal-html-5[]
http --form --multipart --ignore-stdin POST https://validator.w3.org/nu/ out='json' content=${content} | jq
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: validate
#+begin_src json
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "type": "info",
      "lastLine": 3,
      "firstLine": 1,
      "lastColumn": 7,
      "firstColumn": 16,
      "subType": "warning",
      "message": "Consider adding a “lang” attribute to the “html” start tag to declare the language of this document.",
      "extract": "TYPE html>\n\n<title>Hello?",
      "hiliteStart": 10,
      "hiliteLength": 9
    }
  ],
  "source": {
    "type": "text/html",
    "encoding": "utf-8",
    "code": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n\n<title>Hello?</title>\n\n<p>Is it valid at all?</p>"
  }
}
#+end_src
```

The I can reuse it to validate another HTML block:

```
#+name: html-with-root
#+begin_src html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <title>Rooted HTML 5</title>

  <p>Is it more valid?</p>
</html>
#+end_src

#+call: validate(content=html-with-root[])

#+RESULTS:
#+begin_src json
{
  "messages": [],
  "source": {
    "type": "text/html",
    "encoding": "utf-8",
    "code": "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang=\"en\">\n  <title>Rooted HTML 5</title>\n\n  <p>Is it more valid?</p>\n</html>"
  }
}
#+end_src
```

It's quite good, but every time I need to give each block a unique name and then call the validator, referring to that name with square brackets. What I would really like, is to just evaluate the HTML code block and get the validation as a result. I think the way is to do something like:

```
(defun org-babel-execute:html (body params)
  "Validate given HTML using W3C Validator"
  (some-magic-function validate body))
```

The closest to "some-magic-function" I found so far is the `org-sbe` macro, but it's designed for table formulas, and in any case I couldn't get it to work.